# How to rewrite state correctly in filters React

Tags: reactjs, filter, state

I need to use an input filter in React. I have a list of activities and need to filter them like filters on the picture. If the icons are unchecked, actions with these types of activities should not be showed. It works.

The problem that when I use input filter and write letters it works. But when I delete letter by letter nothing changes.

I understand that the problem is that I write the result in the state. And the state is changed.But how to rewrite it correctly.
[image: filter example]

```
const [activities, setActivities] = useState(allActivities);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(1);
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const switchType = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=> {
    const currentIndex = checked.indexOf(event.target.value);
    const newChecked = [...checked];

    if (currentIndex === -1) {
      newChecked.push(event.target.value);
    } else {
      newChecked.splice(currentIndex, 1);
    }

//function that shows activities if they are checked or unchecked
    
setChecked(newChecked);

    const res = allActivities.filter(({ type }) => !newChecked.includes(type));
    setActivities(res);
  };
//shows input filter
  const inputSearch = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    
    const foundItems = activities.filter(
      (item) => item.activity.indexOf(event.target.value) > -1
    );

    setActivities(foundItems);
  };
//shows participants filter
  const countSearch = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setValue(Number(event.target.value));
    const participantsSearch = allActivities.filter(
      (item) => item.participants >= event.target.value
    );
    setActivities(participantsSearch);
  };
```

This is render part

```
  <Input
            onChange={inputSearch}       
               startAdornment={
              <InputAdornment position="start">
                <SearchIcon />
              </InputAdornment>
            }
          />
 <Input
            onChange={countSearch}
            type="number"
            value={props.value}
                      startAdornment={
              <InputAdornment
                position="start"
                className={classes.participantsTextField}
              >
                <PersonIcon />
              </InputAdornment>
            }
          />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you save over the state that you are filtering, so each time a filter is applied the data ***can only*** decrease in size or remain the same. It can never reset back to the full, unfiltered data.

Also with the way you've written the checkbox and input callbacks you can't easily mix the two.

Since the filtered data is essentially "derived" state from the `allActivities` prop, and the `value` and `checked` state, it really shouldn't also be stored in state. You can filter `allActivities` inline when rendering.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState<sting>('');
const [checked, setChecked] = useState<string[]>([]);

const switchType = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=> {
  const currentIndex = checked.indexOf(event.target.value);

  if (currentIndex === -1) {
    setChecked(checked => [...checked, event.target.value]);
  } else {
    setChecked(checked => checked.filter((el, i) => i !== currentIndex);
  }
};

const inputSearch = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  setValue(event.target.value.toLowerCase());
};

...

return (
  ...

  {allActivites.filter(({ activity, type }) => {
      if (activity || type) {
        if (type) {
          return checked.includes(type);
        }
        if (activity) {
          return activity.toLowerCase().includes(value);
        }
      }
      return true; // return all
    })
    .map(.....
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with your `inputSearch` code.
Each time you do `setActivities(foundItems);` you narrow down the state of your `activities` list. So when you start deleting, you don't see any change because you removed the rest of the activities from the state.

You'll want to take out `allActivities` into a const, and always filter `allActivities` in `inputSearch`, like so:

```
const allActivities = ['aero', 'aeroba', 'aerona', 'aeronau'];
const [activities, setActivities] = useState(allActivities);

// ...rest of your code

const inputSearch = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  const foundItems = allActivities.filter(
    (item) => item.activity.indexOf(event.target.value) > -1
  );
  setActivities(foundItems);
};
// ...rest of your code
```

Comment: I agree with this variant, but in this variant we filter all activities. And I need to filter those that were choosen after checkbox filter. In another words, all filters are connected. If I choose sport and social activities, the input filter have to show activities with this typy, but not all.